# How do I properly sanitize data received from a text area, when outputting it back into the text area?

Tags: php, mysql, html, forms, sanitization

A user will input text in a textarea. It is then inserted directly into a mySQL database. I use trim, htmlentities, mysql_real_escape_string on it and I have magic quotes enabled. How should I sanitize it when outputting that data back into a textarea?

Thanks for your help. I've never been too sure on the correct way of doing this...

Comment: I'd recommend disabling magic quotes, it will only cause problems later on.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You shouldn't use `htmlentities` when saving it. You should use `htmlentities` when displaying it. The rule of thumb is not to encode/sanitize the data until you need to. If you do `htmlentities` on it when you save then you have to do `html_entity_decode` on the text when the user wants to edit the input. So you sanitize for what you need and nothing more. When saving it, you need to sanitize for SQL injection, so you `mysql_real_escape_string` it. When displaying, you need to sanitize for XSS, so you `htmlentities` it.

Also, I am not sure if you saw Darryl Hein's comment, but you really do not want magic_quotes enabled. [They are a bad, bad, thing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_quotes#Criticism) and have been deprecated as of PHP 5.3 and will be gone altogether in PHP 6.

Comment: Should that be the only precaution I take?

Comment: If you're okay with not allowing HTML in whatever the string is, that is all. If you want HTML to be allowed then you go down a very dangerous road of white lists and whatnot.

Comment: Just a side note, does this hold true when BBCode parsing too?

Comment: Well, for that I would make an exception. Since message boards sometimes can be very busy, having to translate BBCode on every page view would be pretty expensive. At that point it would be better to have an encoded_field and a raw_field, the former to display and the latter to show when editing.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Paolo's answer about when to use `htmlentities()`, unless you're using an old version of PHP, the correct way to sanitize for insertion into a mysql DB is to use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) which are part of the [mysqli extension](http://php.net/mysqli). This replaces any need to use `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

Other than that, I think you've got things covered.

Comment: note that using prepared statements is not enough, you have to use bound parameters. IOW: use '?' in the SQL string, and send the data with stmt->bind_param()

Comment: In normal workflows, wouldn't you want to catch the invalid text before reaching the prepare statement? In which case, isn't it suitable to use mysql_real_escape_string