# Finding and displaying a string from a MYSQL database?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql database called tafe06_stories with title, author and content rows.

I have a html form with a search field

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Search the Database</title>
    </head>

    <body>

    <form action="search.php" method="post">
     Search: <input type="text" name="search" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

this activates search.php, what I'm looking to do is search the stories table and display the the search term or terms in context, with 5 or so words either side of it. (Doesn't have to be exact). So for example if I searched for "dog", and one of the stories contains a sentence like "it was a rainy day and the dog was very wet", I want it to print out something like "day and dog was very".

Here is search.php

```
<?php
mysql_connect ("localhost", "tafe0_steven2","password")  or die (mysql_error());  
mysql_select_db ("tafe06_stories");             
?>
```

I just need some help passing the search term to the `search.php` page and then querying the database in php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect ("localhost", "tafe0_steven2","password")  or die (mysql_error());  
mysql_select_db ("tafe06_stories",$con);             
// Try here your search query 
?>
```

Comment: where does the search term get passed to? is it in a variable somewhere?

Comment: The term being searched is available in global PHP variables $_POST and $_REQUEST.  **$search=@$_REQUEST['search'];**
Also read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/593238/how-do-i-properly-sanitize-data-received-from-a-text-area-when-outputting-it-ba