# prevent from using HTML tags inside textbox

Tags: html

Is there a way I can prevent users from using HTML tags like `<br>` inside the `textbox` or any other html tags to be displayed as text:

```
<form method="POST">
    <textarea id="note" placeholder="Type your notes here"></textarea>
    <input type="button" value="Save Note" />
</form>
```

Comment: htmlentities? htmlspecialchars? ... have a look at this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I properly sanitize data received from a text area, when outputting it back into the text area?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/593238/how-do-i-properly-sanitize-data-received-from-a-text-area-when-outputting-it-ba)

Answer (score 0):

Just strip out any html tags they might use with this:

```
var myString = document.getElementById('note');
var stringStripped = myString.replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, '');
```

or with the first line using jQuery if you prefer:

```
var myString = $('#note');
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is write some JavaScript that is invoked upon form submission and would prevent it if one of the fields contains XML-like content. You can check that with an appropriate Regex.

You do understand though, that would not actually prevent an attacker from still sending HTML through those fields, or a browser with JavaScript disabled. To handle that case, your protection should be server side, where you will need to run the fields against the same Regex to validate they don't contain HTML and reject the form submission if they do.